# Como funciona o método get()?

Tags: java

Queria entender o método `get()`, como ele funciona e pra que está servindo nesse código (*de preferencia queria uma explicação de forma imaginária sem nomes técnicos*).

```
package exemplo_oo;

public class Game {

    private Player player;
    private Inimigo inimigo;
    
    public Game() {
        player = new Player();
        inimigo = new Inimigo();
    }
    
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    
    public Inimigo getInimigo() {
        return inimigo;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        Player player = game.getPlayer();
        player.atacarInimigo(game.getInimigo());
        System.out.println(game.getInimigo().life);
    }
    
}
```

---

```
package exemplo_oo;

public class Player {
    private int life = 100;
    
    public void atacarInimigo(Inimigo inimigo) {
        inimigo.life--;
    }
}

    package exemplo_oo;

public class Inimigo {
    public int life = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um método `get()` usualmente tem como objetivo obter um valor, um objeto ou até uma classe.

Depois dê uma olhada em polimorfismo e encapsulamento.

Tentando deixar de forma clara, a partir do seu exemplo:

O método `getPlayer()` te retorna um objeto do tipo `Player`, por isso a sua variável `player` pode ser atribuída a esse método get. Ou seja, ele pega um objeto do tipo `Player` que pertence a classe `Game` e atribui em sua váriavel `player`.

Para tentar deixar um pouco mais claro:

Usando o exemplo to método `getInimigo()`:

Como dito, o método vai retornar um objeto do tipo `Inimigo`, e isso quer dizer que você pode ter acesso a métodos e variáveis **públicas** dessa classe `Inimigos`, por isso ele consegue acessar a variável `life` definida na classe `Inimigos`.

Ou seja, ao chamar um método `get()`, usualmente você vai obter algo de retorno, do tipo definido.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Higor: métodos get (assim como métodos set) também é  uma convenção. Nada impede que você use retornarInimigo em vez de getInimigo. Mas como toda convenção, está ali para te ajudar. IDEs implementam facilitadores de geração de código para vocẽ e há até mesmo uma biblioteca (https://projectlombok.org/) que fornece anotações que geram os getters e setters em tempo de compilação.

No caso de componentes JavaBeans não é apenas uma convenção mas um dos 3 itens a serem implementados (os outros dois são ter um construtor sem argumentos e implementar java.io.Serializable).